# Passing a variable from jQuery to PHP script so that I know how many times to loop?

Tags: php, jquery, post

I currently am unable to pass a variable from a jQuery script to a PHP script which would allow me to know how many times I have to use a loop. I have the count variable in the jQuery that I need to post to the PHP script but just unsure on how to do it.

I am able to get both of these variables `$_POST['skill-'.$i.'']` & `$_POST['amount-'.$i.'']` but it is just a matter of passing the variable `count` which defines the amount of times I have to loop through these:

jQuery:

```
$.fn.addSlide = function () {
return this.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $num = $('.slide').length++,
        $name = $('<input type="text" class="textbox" name="skill-' + $num + '" placeholder="What\'s your skill?"></div>'),
        $slide = $('<div class="slide" id="slider-' + $num + '"></div>'),
        $amt = $('<input name="amount-' + $num + '" id="amount-' + $num + '" readonly placeholder="0"/><br>');
    $this.append($name).append($slide).append($amt);
    $slide.slider({
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        step: 1,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $amt.val("" + ui.value);
        }
    });
});
}

$('body').on('click', '.addNew', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$('#container').addSlide();
}); 

var count = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){   
$('.addNew').click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#length').html(count);       
    count++;
});

$('.save').click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("file.php", { data: count } );   
});

});
```

PHP:

```
$i = 0;

while($_POST['count'] >= $i){
    echo $_POST['skill-'.$i.''];
    echo $_POST['amount-'.$i.'']."<br><br>";

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Two things: The count will be in `$_POST['data']`, since that's the key in the object you passed to `jQuery.post`, and when that POST returns, you don't do anything with its response. Echoing HTML in the PHP file will not result in anything appearing on the screen.

Comment: @DanGrossman Well what do I have to do in order for this to work because I'm getting confused now as you answered the question then deleted it. So I'm assuming that your answer was correct or is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be generating `<INPUT>`s for your "skill-" fields. Perhaps "count" should be a hidden INPUT up there, too.

Shouldn't you also serializing a `<FORM>` containing all those INPUTs, if you expect to have that data in the AJAX POST? Otherwise you're just sending "count", and not the actual counted data fields.

You've got too little actual concrete structure in your HTML, for it to be clear where your dynamically-generated stuff is appended to;  or for me to bother figuring out where the  element should go around.

Write. Clear. Simple. Code.

Use something like `<div id='skillDiv'>`, build your elements up, and then (in one single place) `appendTo('#skillDiv')`.

So amazingly clear, people could even read, debug & follow your code.

Comment: look I'm trying to solve this problem and get this part of what I'm doing finished. If you could give me a fix for it then that would be great? appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Well, what I said. Put a `<INPUT type='hidden' name='count'>` hidden field up there, wrap it all in a `<FORM id='form'>`, and then submit the form or AJAX post `('#form').serialize()`. That will send all your desired data, exactly as I said.

Comment: Thanks I done what you said and it was really easy. Just not used to JS, Thanks for the help!!